# "Advanced" section for a form that has two columns

Tags: html, css, forms, layout, css-grid

So, I have a form that has a couple of rows with settings.
The whole thing is a grid, where the first column is as wide as the widest item.

Now I've decided to move some of the rows into an "advanced" section, using the `<details>` element. The problem with this though, is that this is a different container, meaning the components in it aren't part of the forms layout anymore.

What would be the idiomatic way to solve this, preferably without magic javascript or libraries.

Here's my example:

```html
<html>
    <head>
    <style>
        .example-form-layout {
            display: inline-grid;
            grid-template-columns: auto auto;
            gap: 5px 5px;

            align-items: center;
        }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <p>Form:</p>
        <form id="example-form" class="example-form-layout">
            <!--col one-->
            <b>Setting one</b>
            <!--col two-->
            <input type="number" name="setting_one"/>

            <!--col one-->
            <b>Setting two (Longer name)</b>
            <!--col two-->
            <input type="number" name="setting_two"/>

            <details class="example-form-details">
                <!--col one-->
                <b>Setting two</b>
                <!--col two-->
                <input type="number" name="setting_two"/>
            </details>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what should be the reason for rows into? media query? And you would not do it **correctly** without javascript.

Comment: Uhm, I am sorry, I don't know what you mean with your first question.

And I think layouting should rely on JS as little as possible, as it spreads and obfuscates the layouting code, make the code less maintainable and more confusing and harder to debug.

Comment: 1. But there are tasks that cannot be solved without javascript. If without js, then you can simply duplicate the necessary items in the section to which you want to transfer, and set these items to display: none, but this is not a stucco way. And better think about javasript. 2. I meant by what event the items should be moved.

Comment: I was intending to use the `details` element. Try out the demo, it allows you to expand content. It's mostly used for when you've got a text that's very big and you don't want it to show all at once, but don't want to use JS or a link either. It works well for that purpose. And the thing is, I don't know whether this is possible without JS, that's why I am asking here :)

Comment: Let's be clear, I could easily achieve this with Javascript ^^

Answer (score -1):

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style>
    .example-form-layout {
        display: inline-grid;
        grid-template-columns: auto auto;
        gap: 5px 5px;

        align-items: center;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
    <p>Form:</p>
    <form id="example-form" class="example-form-layout">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-sm">
                One of three columns
                <b>Setting one</b>
                <b>Setting two (Longer name)</b>
                <b>Setting two</b>
              </div>
              <div class="col-sm">
                One of three columns
                <input type="number" name="setting_one"/>
                <input type="number" name="setting_two"/>
                <details class="example-form-details">
                    <input type="number" name="setting_two"/>
                </details>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the answer, but this introduces 3 additional dependencies and therefore isn't a simple solution to the problem. On top of that, there's no explanation as to why or how this works.